# SWT runs on a different version of java

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

First and foremost, I know very little about Java and even less about SWT, so bare with me here. Earlier today I tried to run this simple program I found on https://mkyong.com/swt/swt-hello-world-example

**here is the code:**

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class SWTHelloWorld {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    
    Text helloWorldTest = new Text(shell, SWT.NONE);
    helloWorldTest.setText("Hello World SWT");
    helloWorldTest.pack();
    
    shell.pack();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
```

**When I run it I get this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

What I understand from this is that SWT is getting compiled with Java 11 when it should be compiled with Java 8, BUT -and that's a big BUT- I don't have Java 11 I deleted it to only have Java 8 and avoid this kind of problems.
When I run in my terminal the commands java -version and javac -version in both cases i get this version '1.8.0_331' and there is nothing else. I also checked my settings and configurations in Eclipse and everything seems to be set to run on Java 8. Ultimately I tried this command in the terminal `javac -target 1.8.0_331 SWTHelloWorld.java` to target the right compiler, but I got `javac: invalid target release: 1.8.0_331`. I don't know where to go from there. Anyone?

Thanks in advance guys!

PS: I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.4 if that matters.

Comment: I don't think SWT is still supported.  If you can, I'd strongly recommend using Swing or JavaFX if a thick client is an absolutely.  A thin client is by far superior.

Comment: I don't know what thick and thin client means (I told you, I don't know much), but are you sure that SWT is not supported? How could I check?

Comment: I'm not sure it's no longer supported.  But I would be very surprised if it was. It was never all that popular as it was difficult to use.  A thick client is what you're doing, java code creating a UI in its own executable. A thin client is a web interface, think of any major website, that's a thin client.

Comment: oh ok thank you for educating me on that, but I can't find anywhere that says swt is not supported by Java 8

Comment: I would go as far as to say Java is dead on the desktop. Most professional uses of Java today are server side. Developing a desktop GUI in Java is really only good for study purposes or purely personal use. If this is what you're using it for then the previous advice is good. Use javafx or maybe swing. The former is better

Comment: @Ryan SWT is still supported, it is part of Eclipse and is actively developed

Comment: The current version of SWT is compiled using Java 11 and requires Java 11 to run like the rest of Eclipse.

Comment: what other version of SWT can be run with Java 8? And how can I change my version of SWT to one that works with Java 8?

Comment: Eclipse 4.16 was the last release compiled to run on Java 8. The archive site for this is [here](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.16-202006040540/) and includes an SWT download. However since this is old it may not run on the latest version of some operating systems (macOS especially)

Comment: So I just need to delete the swt.jar and eclipse on my computer and reinstall everything with the right version? (I feel like such a newbie asking that)

Comment: You would be far better off using the current Eclipse + SWT and Java 17. Java 8 is pretty ancient now. Older versions of SWT had issues on macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling Java 11 does not change which version SWT itself was compiled for. Your application requires at least Java 11 because a library you're using, SWT, requires it.

Comment: How do you know that it requires that? Do you have a source? I can't find one.

Comment: Eclipse has required Java 11 to run for a few years. Without knowing which download you have, I'm going by the class file version in the error message and the execution environment specified in https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .